# When is the Python 3.12 __buffer__ method invoked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.12

Python 3.12 [introduced](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-688-making-the-buffer-protocol-accessible-in-python) the `__buffer__` method.

I have something like `get_view(self) -> memoryview:` to get the view of my data.
Now I think I could use `__buffer__(self, flags) -> memoryview` instead.

If I just pass my object to where I currently use a memoryview it (obviously) does not convert my object to a memoryview.
Currently I am stuck when and where is the `__buffer__` method actually invoked?

Comment: It's called ["...when a buffer is requested from _self_ (for example, by the `memoryview` constructor)."](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__buffer__)